# nav menu item is jumping on a different menu item in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am maintaining a wordpress page which is using devdmbootstrap3, and has a navigation bar which has 5 different menu items on it. There is a page name "Our Team" and when inspect the element, it has "post-type-archive post-type-archive-team" and I guess this page is behaving as a post-page, on the other hand there is a main "New & Articles" page which is the main posts page( it was chosen as a Posts Page on static front page). When I click on "Our Team" on navigation bar, it jumps on News & Article first, I made a fix with Jquery with removing all those div classes that I mentioned above and fed regular page features but i don't think that is a good practice, and it seems like it is jumping on news & article menu item first then appears on our team menu item.

[image: Here what it looks like]

It is acting like a child menu of news&articles page,.

What i tried so far is:

1- I checked Admin>Pages>Our team page if it has a parent page or not

2- Made a Jquery removeClass and addClass to give a regular page behaviors

3-Disabled plugins and tried one by one if there is any conflict.

For your information, this is custom wordpress page.

Did anyone have the same issue that can lead me a good, long term solution? Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Did you check the menu? In the wordpress menus under Appearance. Also, it could be possible that you are missing one of the template files. archive.php

Comment: i do have archive.php